# How can I determine the start non-terminal of a CFG?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

Suppose I have a grammar such that there exist $n$ production rules which contain only terminal symbols, and none of these rules produce the same terminal (*disjoint*).

> $A ::= x|y|z$
>
> $B ::= a|b|c$
>
> ...
>
> $N ::= l|m|k$

Further suppose that I cannot simply merge these production rules together as they are used in different parts of the grammar.

How can I hence determine or rather choose, the start non-terminal $S$, for purposes of $LL(1)$ parsing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a grammar is a tuple $(N,T,P,S)$ where $N$ is the set of non-terminals, $T$ is the set of terminals, $P$ is the set of productions, and $S \in N$ is the start symbol.

Therefore if you have a grammar you already have $S$ (and if you don't know $S$ then you don't have a grammar).

Comment: I see, then I have to check with who gave me the productions.

Comment: A common convention is that the non-terminal at the left hand side of the first production is start symbol. But the given grammar makes no sense, it just generates a set of words from *one* non-terminal, all the others are useless (as they can't be used at all).

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, however I did not list the entire grammar here.